# Alinear arbol de bootstrap según resolución

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap

Tengo este árbol que a la resolución 1366 x 768 se ve bien cuando se despliega.
Mi problema es que cuando se  ve en otra resolución, se descuadra. He intentado hacer las medidas con % en vez de px tambíen con vw, darle un tamaño width a todos los div, usar position absolute, relative y demás pero nada me funciona. Solo se mantiene la posición si el position   le pongo fixed.

```js
$(function () {
    $('.tree li:has(ul)').addClass('parent_li').find(' > span').attr('title', 'Collapse this branch');

    $('.tree li.parent_li > span').on('click', function (e) {
        var children = $(this).parent('li.parent_li').find(' > ul > li');
        if (children.is(":visible")) {
            children.hide('fast');
            $(this).attr('title', 'Expand').find(' > i').addClass('glyphicon-plus-sign').removeClass('glyphicon-minus-sign');
        } else {
            children.show('fast');
            $(this).attr('title', 'Collapse').find(' > i').addClass('glyphicon-minus-sign').removeClass('glyphicon-plus-sign');
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

});



#task_flyout {
height:20px; 
background-color:#dedede;
 position: relative;
}

.fixed {position:fixed; top:0; left:3.1%;  z-index:2; width:100%; color:black;}

.tree {
min-height:20px;
padding:5px 0px 0px 0px;
margin-bottom:20px;
background-color:transparent;
border:0px solid #999;
color: #686a10;
   font-weight: bold;
   
}


#arbol{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
}

#arbolTree{
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
width:100%;
}


.tree li {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0.5% 0% 0 0.3%;
position:relative;
}
.tree li::before, .tree li::after {
content:'';
left:0%;
position:absolute;
right:auto
}
.tree li::before {
border-left:1px solid #999;
bottom:50px;
height:100%;
top:0;
width:1px;
}
.tree li::after {
border-top:1px solid #999;
height:auto;
top:29px;
width:100%;
}
.tree li span {
   
display:inline-block;
padding:3px 0px;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight: bold;
}
.tree li.parent_li>span {
cursor:pointer;
color: black;
}
.tree>ul>li::before, .tree>ul>li::after {
border:0;
padding-bottom: 4px  !important;
}
.tree li:last-child::before {
   
}
.tree li.parent_li>span:hover, .tree li.parent_li>span:hover {
background:transparent;
color:#686a10;
}



.prsp{ /* Tabla Presupuestos */
display: inline-block;
color: black;
position: absolute;
  
}


.totCntSig{ /* Tabla Presupuestos */
display: inline-block;
color: black;
}


.id{ /* Tabla Presupuestos */

display:none;

}

.hrTree{ /* Esto es un hr modificado por mi*/
margin-top: 0%;
margin-bottom: 0%;
border: 0;
border-top: 0px solid #999999;
box-sizing: content-box;

}

.sombreadoWell{

min-height: 20px;
padding: 5px;
margin-bottom: 2px;
background-color: transparent;
border: 1px solid #afb159;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);

}


/*--------------------Totales-----------------------*/

#Total
{ /* Esto es un hr modificado por mi*/
width: 47.7%;
display: inline-block;
}

#sumTotCntAnt
{ /* Esto es un hr modificado por mi*/
 position: relative;
left: 48.2%;
display: inline-block;
}

#sumTotCntEje
{ /* Esto es un hr modificado por mi*/
position: relative;
left: 60.1%;
display: inline-block;
}

#sumTotCntSig
{ /* Esto es un hr modificado por mi*/
 position: relative;
left: 70.3%;
display: inline-block;
}

#sumTotCntJust
{ /* Esto es un hr modificado por mi*/
position: relative;
left: 81%;
display: inline-block;
}



/*Etiquetas de arbol------------------------------------------------------------*/
#pht /* Lbl Proyectos */
{ 
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
left: 3%;

}

#prsp /*Lbl Presupuestos */
{ 
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
left: 20%;
 
}
#ejer2018 /*Lbl Ejercicio 2018*/
{ 
position: relative;
  left: 60.1%;
  display: inline-block;
}


#eje2018
{ 
 position: relative;
left: 48.2%;
display: inline-block;
}


#prop2019
{ 
 position: relative;
left: 70.3%;
display: inline-block;
}

#men2019
{ 
position: relative;
left: 81%;
display: inline-block;
}

#prspName{
position: relative;
  
}


/* Clases de nombres Proyectos, historias, tareas y presupuestos*/

.pryName{ /* Nombre de proyectos*/
display: inline-block;

}

.hisName{ /* Nombre de historia */
display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
  left: 2%;
}

.tarName{ /* Nombre de tarea */
display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 left: 2%;
  
}

.prspName{ /* Tabla Presupuestos */
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
left: 20%;
}


.ejecutado2018{
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
left: 48.2%;
}

.ejercicio2018{
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
left: 60.1%;
}

.propuesta2019{
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
left: 70.3%;
}


.memoria2019{
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
left: 81%;
}


.presupuesto{
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tree well">

  <ul>
    <li id='pryName' "+pry.id+" class='liPryName '> <span> <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down'></i> </span>
      <div class='pryName cursor'>pry.name</div>
      <div id='totCntAnt"+ pry.id +"' class='prsp  sumPryCntAnt'> CntAnt</div>
      <div id='totCntEje"+ pry.id +"' class='prsp  sumPryCntEje'> CntEje</div>
      <div id='totCntSig"+ pry.id +"' class='prsp sumPryCntSig'> cntSig</div>
      <div id='totCntJust"+ pry.id +"' class='prsp sumPryCntJust'>CntJust</div>
      <ul>
        <li id='hisName' "+his.id+" class='liHisName'><span><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign'></i> </span>
          <div class='id'>his.id</div>
          <div class='hisName cursor'>his.name</div>
          <div id='cntAnt"+ his.id +"' class='prsp sumHisCntAnt'> sumHisCntAnt</div>
          <div id='cntEje"+ his.id +"' class='prsp sumHisCntEje'> sumHisCntEje</div>
          <div id='cntSig"+ his.id +"' class='prsp sumHisCntSig'> sumHisCntSig</div>
          <div id='cntJust"+ his.id +"' class='prsp sumHisCntJust '> sumHisCntJust</div>
          <ul>
            <li id='tarName' "+tar.id+" class='liTarName'> <span><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign'></i></span>
              <div class='id'>tar.id</div>
              <div class='tarName cursor'>tar.name</div>
              <div id='cnt_ant"+ tar.id +"' class='prsp sumCntAnt'> sumCntAnt</div>
              <div id='cnt_eje"+ tar.id +"' class='prsp sumCntEje'>SumCntEje</div>
              <div id='cnt_sig"+ tar.id +"' class='prsp sumCntSig'>sumCntSig</div>
              <div id='cnt_just"+ tar.id +"' class='prsp sumCntJust'>SumCntSig</div>
              <ul>
                <li id='prspName' "+prsp.id+" class='liPrspName'>
                  <div class='id'>prsp.id</div><span <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign spanPrsp'></i> </span>
                  <div class=' prspName cursor'>prsp.name</div>
                  <div class=' cnt_ant'>prsp.cnt_ant</div>
                  <div class=' cnt_eje'>prsp.cnt_eje</div>
                  <div class=' cnt_sig'>prsp.cnt_sig</div>
                  <div class='cnt_just'>prsp.cnt_just</div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: me alegro de que encontraras una solución al problema. Por favor, edita la pregunta para dejarla como estaba antes y pon la respuesta en la zona de respuestas. Lee [answer] y vuelve a completar el [tour] para más información.

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucione  cambiando position en el css a stiky;

```
#pht { display: inline-block;position: sticky;left: 3%;}
```

De esta forma puedo alinear cualquier div con un mismo left, he hecho una clase left para cada columna y listo.

Comment: Gracias por compartir tu solución!.